# What is the relationship between spaces and organizations in Bluemix?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-tools

- Does each organization allow multiple spaces?
- Are spaces meant for separation of projects?
- What is the best practices in using organizations and spaces on Bluemix?

Through eclipse:

[image]

Through the browser:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is actually a [Bluemix documentation page on Organization and Spaces](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/acctmgmt/index.html#organdspaces).

An organization is the highest concept. When you create an account you get your own "organization". You can invite others to your organization, can get invited to join other organizations or create organizations.

Spaces are used to group related apps and services together. There can be multiple spaces within an organization. When an app or service is created, you have to assign a space.

Answer (score 2):

I use only one organization for my projects, and I have some shared organizations with other developers (for common projects).

Then, I have distinct spaces for development, quality and production.

Answer (score 1):

Please go and read the [Bluemix documentation page on Organization and Spaces](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/acctmgmt/index.html#organdspaces).

Most users will set up two or three different spaces within their organization, with one space being for "production" applications, and the other two spaces used for "development" and/or "testing" or "QA".  You can then use the IBM DevOps services deployment pipeline to auto-deploy your application to your development space, and then provide a deployment stage that will deploy your application to the testing space, and another manual deployment stage that will deploy your application to the production space.  For an example of how to do this, check out my blog post on [Using Bluemix DevOps Services to Support Multiple Deployments](https://dtoczala.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/using-bluemix-devops-services-to-support-multiple-deployments/).

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand :

1. **[Account](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/users_roles.html#userroles)** : kind of your plan, you can have more than one, you can have  *Owner Role* or *Member Role*.

   2. **[Organisation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/users_roles.html#cfroles)**: the highest concept, you can have more than one, your role can be *Manager* / *Biling Manager* / *Auditor*.

      1. **Space** : used to group related Cloud Foundry apps and services together, you can have *Manager Role* / *Developer Role* / *Auditor Role*.
      2. **Namespace** : used to group related Cloud Foundry Containers or Kubernetes clusters, you can have *Administrator Role* / *Operator Role* / *Editor Role* / *Viewer Role* and maybe set other [custom Kubernetes role](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#api-overview).